# Dojox Mobile FilteredListMixin

Tags: dojo

If I load Dojo from the CDN, everything works perfectly fine.  If I load it locally, the mixin doesn't work, and I get the following error in the console:

07-01 02:47:22.428: E/Web Console(7881): Error: declare: mixin #1 is not a callable constructor. at file:///android_asset/www/libs/dojo/dojo/dojo.js:15

Here is an example.  This works fine:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad:true, mblForceBookmarkable:true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([ "dojox/mobile/parser", "dojox/mobile", "dojox/mobile/View", "dojox/mobile/Heading", "dojox/mobile/RoundRectList", "dojox/mobile/ScrollableView", "dojox/mobile/ContentPane", "dojox/mobile/TextBox", "dojox/mobile/EdgeToEdgeList", "dojox/mobile/FilteredListMixin"]);
</script>
<link href="libs/dojo/dojox/mobile/themes/iphone/iphone.css" media="screen"
    rel="stylesheet" title="no title" type="text/css">
<link href="libs/dojo/dojox/mobile/themes/iphone/Accordion.css" media="screen"
    rel="stylesheet" title="no title" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="search" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/View">
        <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading"
            data-dojo-props="fixed: 'top'">Filtered RoundRectList</h1>
        <ul id="list" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/RoundRectList"
            data-dojo-mixins="dojox/mobile/FilteredListMixin"
            data-dojo-props="placeHolder: 'Search'">

            <li data-dojo-props='moveTo:"1.information", transition:"slide"'
                data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem">Information</li>

            <li data-dojo-props='moveTo:"1.urgency", transition:"slide"'
                data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem">Urgency</li>

            <li data-dojo-props='moveTo:"1.data", transition:"slide"'
                data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/ListItem">Data</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I change the script src from the CDN reference, and use this:

```
<script src="libs/dojo/dojo/dojo.js" type="text/javascript" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad:true, mblForceBookmarkable: true"></script>
```

Then it doesn't work anymore.  I am using the standard dojo-release-1.9.1.  My libs folder contains the following files:

"dojo/dojo/dojo.js"
   "dojo/dojox/mobile.js"
   "dojo/dojox/mobile" (entire folder including all subfolders)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

--Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lib directory is missing the dijit/ folder.
Indeed, dojox/mobile has some dependencies on several dijit modules (for ex, FilterListMixin requires 'dijit/registry'), and, according to what you describe, these modules are not available in your libs folder.
Copy the dijit/ folder into your root dojo/ directory and hopefully it should work the same.

Comment: That did the trick, I rebuilt Dojo with dijit/registry included and the mixin works like a charm. Thank you SO much!